# Unknown error in UFT11.53

Tags: hp-uft

I'm using UFT 11.53 for automation and maintaining the scripts in QC.

While executing the scripts in debug mode, my system got hanged and so I had to kill the UFT processes and restart. But after killing the session, I couldn't reopen the test due to some unexpected error (** attached error screenshot below for your reference).

[image]

Please help me in overcoming this issue. Thanks!

*** included Stack Trace scrennshots

[image]

[image]

Comment: The most useful part of the error message is the stack trace and the method call (the method call and error message is obscured in your screen shot), the stack trace is on a separate tab.  The library 'mscorlib' is related to the core .NET framework.  Please post the full details of the error.

Comment: Included the Stack Trace screenshots - please let me know for any other information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stack trace appears to show an error with building a GUID value.  Those are used frequently in software to identify elements.  The stack also points to this error happening while trying to load an action, and appears related to an object repository.

I assume this issue only happens with this one test?  If not, you have an issue with UFT and you may need to reinstall.

Otherwise... you should copy your test to a new folder so that you can try different things to recover it.

Try deleting any of the per-action object repository files.  In the folder structure of your test, you'll find a sub-folder for each action.  Delete the 'ObjectRepository.bdb' file from each action folder one-by-one... trying to reopen the test after each attempt.  Instead of deleting, you may have to replace the file with one from a new, empty test instead.

Another option would be to rebuild your test.  Under each action folder is the 'script.mts' file that is a plain-text file storing the VBScript code of that action.  You could copy/paste this code into the actions of a new test to rebuild most of it.  Then you'd just to have rebuild the other settings like associating object repositories, execution settings, etc.  At least you don't lose the code.

Comment: A few suggestions were mentioned.  To help others, please comment on which step solved your issue, and then kindly accept the proposed answer as a solution.

Comment: Yeah sure,,,, placed my corrupted test into different folder and tried accessing,,,,, then it opened without any issues! :)